# Free SSH server needed to test reverse SSH tunnellig from RPI 3

Tags: pi-3, ssh, server

i'm trying to build a reverse ssh tunnel from my Pi (which is behind a NAT) to a remote ssh server.
for that i need a ssh server that i can access its shell to test if the connection succeeded.
Tried several free ssh servers but couldn't access their shell.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Do you require 100% free server? Cheapest VPS from OVH costs about 3GBP / month... That's comparable to cost of the sole electricity to run the computer 24/7...

Comment: Do you have a computer available? You could create a VM and use it to test this if so.

Comment: https://tunnelin.com service provides you a free server for one device, you can test it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google's Compute Engine can help you out. They have a free, basic instance you can access via SSH that doesn't offer much in resources but should be more than sufficient for your needs.

https://cloud.google.com/free/